# Mysql select a column based on when a different column is least

Tags: mysql

This might not make any sense, but what i'm trying to do is select a column based on when another column is least.  For example, I have 3 int columns and 3 varchar columns

In the below example Unit = int, and Link = varchar

```
Unit1|Link1|Unit2|Link2|Unit3|Link3
72|www.google.com|43|www.yahoo.com|9212|www.lycos.com
```

In the above example Unit2 is least so I'd want to select Link2.

This is how i'm selecting least, so any help would be awesome

```
select Least(
                       Coalesce(myTable.Unit1,
                                myTable.Unit2,
                                myTable.Unit3),
                       Coalesce(myTable.Unit1,
                                myTable.Unit2,
                                myTable.Unit3),
                       Coalesce(myTable.Unit1,
                                myTable.Unit2,
                                myTable.Unit3))
                       AS LowestUnit
from myTable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Unit1 = LEAST(Unit1,Unit2,Unit3) THEN Link1 
            WHEN Unit2 = LEAST(Unit1,Unit2,Unit3) THEN Link2
            WHEN Unit3 = LEAST(Unit1,Unit2,Unit3) THEN Link3
       END AS LinkL
```

(You could use an ELSE Link3 in place of that third WHEN for an equivalent result, I just went with checking all three, and letting the ELSE default to NULL.)

Equivalent and more terse:

```
SELECT CASE LEAST(Unit1,Unit2,Unit3)
            WHEN Unit1 THEN Link1 
            WHEN Unit2 THEN Link2
            WHEN Unit3 THEN Link3
       END AS LinkL
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
drop table if exists myTable;

create table myTable
(Unit1 int unsigned not null,
Link1 varchar(50) not null,
Unit2 int unsigned not null,
Link2 varchar(50) not null,
Unit3 int unsigned not null,
Link3 varchar(50) not null
);

insert into myTable values (72,'www.google.com',43,'www.yahoo.com',9212,'www.lycos.com');

select 
case least(Unit1,Unit2,Unit3)
when Unit1 then Link1
when Unit2 then Link2
when Unit3 then Link3
end as Link
from myTable;
```